# How to parse a binary file from file format/structure?

Tags: python, binary

I'm trying to parse for educational purpose-(I known some library already do this) a .FIT file which is binary file.
I have the .FIT protocol and the file structure explained here : https://developer.garmin.com/fit/protocol/

But now I can't grasp my head what the process is to read, for instance, the header the right way using the information providen by the documentation. I've looked upon resources about struct module and reading binary data in Python but I can't make it work.

How can I read for instance, the first byte, then the following, and then again the following 2 bytes and turn them into intelligible values that I can read ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, read the whole file in a bytearray and then get the individual bytes by indexing, or read the bytes directly from the file. I will give an example of the second.

First open the file for reading in bytes format:

```
open('file.fit', 'rb')
```

Now read the first byte which is the header size:

```
hsize = file.read(1)
```

Now `hsize` is a bytearray of length 1; what we want is an integer. We get the integer with:

```
hsize = hsize[0]
```

Now the position of the actual data is hsize
So we start parsing the first record, but first store the position in a variable:

```
record_pos = hsize 
file.seek(record_pos)
rheader = file.read(1)[0]
```

Now we want to know the type of the record. It is stored in the bit 6. To get that bit we do:

```
mtype = rheader>>6 & 1

so now mtype is either 0 or 1. Then we can do:

if mtype: #Definition message
   # get byte 4 (field count)
   file.seek(record_pos + 4)
   field_count = file.read(1)[0]
   ...
    
else:  # Data message
    ...
```

So the first record starts at fit[hsize]

The first byte of the record is the header which is a bits field. We get that